# How to get the value of distance from the following JSON object?

Tags: php, json

I need to get the value **361714** from the following JSON object in PHP. The JSON is obtained using the google distance matrix api.
Link : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=AIzaSyDVfbt8uCHfFTehDjDS-z_XfYF1O-lLDAE

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361714
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13767
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
```

I have tried this :

```
for($f = 0; $f<count($address); $f++)
        {
            $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=" . $for_cust_add . "&destinations=" . $for_add[$f] . "&key=AIzaSyDVfbt8uCHfFTehDjDS-z_XfYF1O-lLDAE";
            $json = file_get_contents($url);
            $details = json_decode($json, true);
            $distance = $details['rows']['elements']['distance']['value'];
            $distance_array[$f] = $distance;
        }
```

It gives the error : elements not defined.

Comment: How does your code looks so far and what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Start with `json_decode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

```
$distance = $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
```

the `$details['rows']['elements']` is an array and you need its first element, hence the added `[0]`

Update - full proof of concept for the json in the question:

```
<?php
$json_file = '
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361714
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13767
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}';

$details = json_decode($json_file, true);
$distance = $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
print_r($distance);
?>
```

The above code prints 361714

Comment: Doesn't json_decode return a stdClass, where you need to use '->' like $details->rows ?

Comment: "rows" is also an array

Comment: @DevNiels Not if you pass 'true' as the second argument to `json_decode()` which returns an associative array instead.

Comment: @Tudor Constantin Still the same error : elements not defined.

Comment: @BobbyJack - thx for the observation, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @MohitGarg - please try again now - I had to modify the answer thanks to Bobby's observation.

Answer (score 0):

The elements and distance are inside an extra array, that's why you cant access them the way you try:

```
$json = '{ "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
           "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
           "rows" : [
              {
                 "elements" : [
                    {
                       "distance" : {
                          "text" : "225 mi",
                          "value" : 361714
                       },
                       "duration" : {
                          "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                          "value" : 13767
                       },
                       "status" : "OK"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ],
           "status" : "OK" }';

$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->rows as $row) {
    foreach ($row->elements as $element) {
        var_dump($element->distance->value);
    }
}
```

1st: decode the json string and get and object;
2nd: access the object 1 by 1, first the rows and then the elements inside the rows;

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first entry returned by the query then try:

```
$distance = $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
```

if you want to inspect all elements:

```
foreach($row in $details['rows'])
  foreach($element in $row['elements'])
    $distance = $element['distance']['value'];
```

In the future, use use *print_r* to debug; then you can see what the actual structure returned by *json_decode* looks like.

```
print_r($details);
```

Answer (score 0):

### use json_decode()

```
//Enter your code here, enjoy!
$json_file = '
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361714
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13767
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}';

// convert the string to a json object
$jsonObject = json_decode($json_file);
// read the distance object
$distance = $jsonObject->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance;
print_r($distance);
echo 'text= ' . $distance->text . ', value = ' . $distance->value;
```